# Can't access directly to my redux store outside component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js, react-redux

I need to access to my store outside component (from a classic function), but when I try to call getState(), I have an error:

> Property 'getState' does not exist on type '(initialState: any) => any'

Here is my store declaration and import:

*store.ts*

```
import storeHolder from '@lib/storeHolder';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './rootSaga';

const bindMiddleware = (middleware: any) => applyMiddleware(...middleware);
const composeEnhancers = (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) || compose;

function configureStore(initialState: any) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeEnhancers(bindMiddleware([sagaMiddleware]))) as any;

  store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  storeHolder.setStore(store);

  return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

*file-where-i-need.ts*

```
import store from '@redux/store';
import moment from 'moment';

export function formatDateFromnow(date: Date) {
  const state = store.getState(); <-- error: Property 'getState' does not exist on type '(initialState: any) => any'

  const { locale } = state.theme.locale;  

  return moment(date).locale(locale).fromNow();
}
```

Any idea of what I did wrong? I read a lot of posts about this, but did not find a solution.

Comment: `store.js` doesn't export a store, it exports a function that creates the store, so you cannot just call `getState` on it. You need to get the actual store instance that is returned from this function and that I assume you pass to `<Provider>` in your root react component. Since you use nexttjs, it is probably a bad idea to try and export the store from some file. A common practice is not accessing the store from non-component function, instead add a parameter `locale` to `formatDateFromnow` and retrieve it from the store in the component that uses `formatDateFromnow`

Comment: Thank you @AlexChashin, it's this, I imported it from storeHolder and all works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to transform your fileINeed to a React hook

```
const useSomethingINeed = () => {
     const state = something// get your state as inside a component

     const { locale } = state.theme.locale

     return {
         format: date => moment(date).locale(locale).fromNow();
     }
}
```

And use it inside your wanted component

```
const MyWantedComponent = () => {
    const something = useSomethingINeed()
   
    const myDate = new Date();
    
    const myProcessedDate = something.format(myDate)

    return (<>something</>)
}
```